# Can R create a barplot image with clickable bars to insert on a webpage?

Tags: r

I know how to create a barplot, and how to stick it on a webpage; e.g, using `hwriteImage` in the [hwriter package](http://www.embl.de/~gpau/hwriter/).

What I'd like is for each bar to be a region which highlights on mouseover, and where each bar has a different link when clicked. Similar to [this map of the U.S.](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html) using the [jQuery maphilight plugin](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/), but for a barplot rather than a map.  I imagine R could calculate the coordinates of the regions around each bar, generate the HTML AREA tag etc and pass this to maphilight quite easily. Has it been done already? I searched but no luck so far.

Comment: Past my bedtime for a full answer but take a look at the `gridSVG` package.

Comment: @Richie Wow - R never ceases to amaze. [This example](http://sjp.co.nz/projects/gridsvg/demos/aqm/) seems to be closest, I guess I can modify that to do bars instead of points. Thanks! Can you post answer so I can accept and close please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/interactive.html), which summarises a couple of methods: `rggobi` and `iplots`. `rggobi` looks pretty promising, though maybe the installation looks a bit involved. `iplots` is only good for scatter plots.

Some other options (I think these are strongest ones at the moment):

### googleVis

The googleVis package interfaces with the google charts API: try `demo(googleVis)` and the third & fourth one are bar chart (there could be more). It has the advantage of being pretty simple to get started with, although these are not R graphics:

```
df=data.frame(country=c("US", "GB", "BR"), val1=c(10,13,14), val2=c(23,12,32))
Column <- gvisColumnChart(df)
plot(Column)
```

### gridSVG

The `gridSVG` exports the current grid graphics to an .svg file that can be included into a webpage. Unlike googleVis, it's R graphics (so you can use grid/ggplot2 which are more familiar). It looks like you may have to know some Javascript to further embellish your plots though (e.g. to animate on mouse over, you use `grid.garnish(...,onmouseover=...)`).

There's some example code you can try [here](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/gridSVG/) (The really awesome ones are [here](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Talks/Genentech2011/) - usually clicking on the "SVG file" link will have the full interactivity/animation.) ([This one](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Talks/Genentech2011/huber.svg.html) is a scatterplot where the points highlight when you move your mouse over them).

As I said - have a look at the package pages, demos, examples, etc to see which suits you.

Comment: Ah, just seen your answer too. Awesome! Thanks.