# R: open an internet link from a text in a plot

Tags: r, text, plot, hyperlink

I was looking a way to open a link to a webpage from an R plot.

That is something like the standard "text" function to write text on a plot, but with an additional option like

```
plot(...)
text( "For more info click here", x, y, link="www.interesting.com")
```

Does such feature exist somewhere in R?

Regards,

Xavier

Comment: Maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321298/can-r-create-a-barplot-image-with-clickable-bars-to-insert-on-a-webpage) is something useful for you.

Comment: I did not know these packages, even if they may not, that is interesting, thanks